# How to find a record created on the previous month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table where new records are added daily. How would I go about finding records created in the previous month?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up a named scope:

```
named_scope :in_last_month, :conditions => [ "records.created_at > ?", 1.month.ago ]
```

To call it (in your controller):

```
Record.in_last_month
```

Comment: You might want to add that you need to add a created_at column, otherwise Rails won't auto-populate it for you.

Comment: The created_at should be included in a default migration which adds "timestamps" automatically. Also note that what I showed here for the named_scope should be enclosed in a lambda as someone nicely noted below...

Comment: This answer does not work in Rails 4. See answer below for Rails 4 usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29904961/336920

Answer (score 11):

The `named_scope` is a rather elegant way to go, I think, but if you take that route you will want to use it with a `lambda` method so that the time doesn't get scoped to when the application is initially loaded.

For example, this:

```
named_scope :last_month, :conditions => 
  ['created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', 
  Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, Date.today.beginning_of_month]
```

will work properly the first month your application is up, but improperly the next month, unless the app gets restarted.

But this:

```
named_scope :last_month, lambda {
  {:conditions => ['created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', 
   Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, Date.today.beginning_of_month]}}
```

will work every time, because the lambda method gets executed on every call, reevaluating the `Date.today`s.

Comment: Note that `Date.today` does not use application timezone. `Date.current` / `Time.current` does.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer and lambda improvement do not work in Rails 4.

Update for Rails 4:

```
scope :last_month, -> {
    where( 'created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', 
            Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, 
            Date.today.beginning_of_month )}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your records are timestamped, you can just do something like this:

```
Thing.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.month])
```

If they're not timestamped, you should start storing the information since it's something you'll want to look up later.

Comment: Alternatively you can do 1.month.ago which is the same thing as Time.now - 1.month.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I ended up going with this:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, Date.today.beginning_of_month])
```

Comment: Note that `Date.today` does not use application timezone. `Date.current` / `Time.current` does.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects i used this way:

```
Thing.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ', DateTime.now.beginning_of_month - 1.month, DateTime.now.beginning_of_month)
```

in Rails 3 using last_month throws an error: `Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month`

> NoMethodError: undefined method `last_month'

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Rails 4+, note that `Date.current` will use your application's timezone (specified in application.rb):

```
scope :created_last_month, lambda {
  where(created_at: Date.current.last_month.beginning_of_month..Date.current.last_month.end_of_month)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "usual" fields on your table?  See the [RoR wiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/MagicFieldNames) for a list of them.  That way, you can express special queries to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thing.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 1.month.ago.at_beginning_of_month])
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good candidate for SQL's **BETWEEN** syntax

```
named_scope :last_month, :conditions => ['created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, Date.today.beginning_of_month])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```rb
last_month = Time.zone.today.last_month # considering time zones
Thing.where(created_at: last_month.all_month)
```